# Are C++ Pointers to Non-Reentrant Qt Data Types Reentrant and Safe to Pass from Main GUI Thread to a Worker Thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, pointers

Hi I have a c++ object (BackupJob) that stores data for backup jobs to be passed between a main GUI thread and a worker thread using Qt signals and slots. It contains lots of reentrant Qt data types like QVectors QStringLists QDateTimes etc which I know are safe to pass between threads... I am considering storing pointers to a QThread, a QObject, and a Win API HANDLE in the backupjob objects. QThread is not reentrant.

Is this safe to do as long as the pointers are passed by value via signals and slots in the backupjob object and the underlying data pointed to is not modified? Are pointers reentrant and can be passed between threads even if the underlying data type pointed to is not reentrant?
I am using the definition of reentrancy as [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html).

The situation might be further complicated by the fact that the thread pointed to in the backupjob object is separate from the main GUI thread and worker thread, monitoring directory changes on its own. The watchDirObject object lives in dirMonThread, with separate dir watching threads for each backupjob. The worker thread performs on demand backups while the dir watching threads detect directory changes in real time. I assume the same underlying principle remains the only relevant thing to consider, whether those pointers are safe to pass between threads.

Thanks!

Here is some code:

```
//executed in main thread
workerThread = new QThread(this);
workerThread->start();
worker = new Worker;
worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
connect(this, SIGNAL(backup(QList<BackupJob>,QList<BackupJob>)), worker, SLOT(backup(QList<BackupJob>,QList<BackupJob>)));

class BackupJob
{
...
QList<std::pair<BBFileInfo, BBFileInfo> > fileList;
QMap<QString,qint64> requiredSize, peakSize;
...
QThread *dirMonThread;
//WatchDirectory QObject moved to dirMonThread
WatchDirectory *watchDirObject;
HANDLE dirMonThreadObjectHandle;
}

//executed in main thread to set up directory watching thread
void Replicator::setupJobContinuousThread(BackupJob &job)
{
if (!CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,job.getName().toStdWString().c_str()))
    win32Error(TEXT("CreateEvent"));
job.setupContinuousThread(this);
connect(job.getContinuousThread(),&QThread::finished,job.getContinuousObject(),&QObject::deleteLater);
connect(job.getContinuousObject(),&WatchDirectory::sendRealTimeOperationJob,this,&Replicator::commitRealTimeOperations);
//connect(replicator,&Replicator::dirMon,job.getContinuousObject(),&WatchDirectory::startWatch);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(job.getContinuousObject(),"startWatch",Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void BackupJob::setupContinuousThread(Replicator *replicator)
{
dirMonThread = new QThread(replicator);
dirMonThread->start();
watchDirObject = new WatchDirectory;
watchDirObject->moveToThread(dirMonThread);
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `QThread` is not reentrant? Also talking about "pointer reentrancy" does not mean anything. A pointer is just an address. You can talk about reentrancy only for functions or classes.

Comment: Can you safely pass pointers from thread to thread as long as you don't access them or modify their contents? That's what I'm mainly concerned about. I am referring to pointer reentrancy drawing a parallel between reentrant classes and pointers in asking whether they behave similar when shared among threads QThread is not listed as reentrant on the API doc page https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html.

Comment: C++ classes are reentrant by default. From Qt doc `C++ classes are often reentrant, simply because they only access their own member data` and `Many Qt classes are reentrant`. Also in Qt doc it is stated that `QObject` are reentrant and a special note is made about GUI classes because they are not reentrant. So unless it is explicitly written somewhere QThread are reentrant.

Comment: Again "pointer reentrancy" does not mean anything. A pointer is just an address to something as such it can be as safely copied across thread as any other integer type. But there is nothing to "enter" or "reenter".

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Most all Qt classes that are reentrant say so in the API doc on the bottom of the first section of the main page for the specific class. They do inadvertently omit it sometimes though as could be the case with QThread.

I just wanted to make sure there were no problems with my code passing pointers around between threads; I was definitely misusing the term reentrant :) My program is a data backup program and as such I don't want any possibility of race conditions that could jeopardize data.